# not getting a new line in xslt

Tags: xslt

New Line in xslt is creating a problem for me. i searched a lot and found many ways of inserting a new line character in xslt. but nothing is working out. I tried using 
`<xsl:text></xsl:text>, <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>` and many such other new line characters. but failed. I dont wanna use any html characters like `<br/>` n all. I just wanna know how will i get a `new line in xslt`.`Does it depend on the os used, processor, xslt version or anything?`

output what i want is:

```
Dear abc,
You Have received a Mail.
```

but i am getting it as:

```
Dear abc, You have received a mail.
```

i even used

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>&#xA; 1 &#xA; 2 &#xA; </xsl:text>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but still it shows 1 2 in one line.

Comment: The stylesheet code with the `xsl:output method="text"` and the `xsl:text` element looks fine to me to achieve what you want.
Can you explain to us how you apply that stylesheet, which XSLT processor you use, how you look at the transformation result?

Comment: @Martin Honnen: `Dim x As New Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
        x.Load("Calls.xslt")
        ' x.Load("\\adserver\DropBox\CRM Mail template\Calls.xslt")
        x.Transform("issuexml.xml", "Modifycalls.html")`     I use this function. I used xslt with .net . does that make any difference for new line . I'm new to xslt so don't know anything deeply about xslt.

Comment: Is the "Calls.xslt" you load with the code the one you posted here? If you want to output plain text then I don't understand why you transform to a file with the suffix ".html". That should be ".txt". And then you should look at the file with a plain text editor. And you haven't explained how you look at the transformation result, if you load a .html document in a browser then of course it treats it as text/html where line breaks don't matter. So that could be one reason for your problem, that you want a .txt file but create a .html file and then look at that in a browser. So try ".txt".

Comment: @Martin Honnen: thanks. I used ".txt" instead of ".html"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the responses in the comment section the cause of your problem seems to be simply that you created a ".html" result file and then looked at that in a browser which applies HTML display rules where new lines are usually simply collapsed to spaces.
So the solution to the problem is to simply ensure you create a ".txt" file instead, that way your new lines will be displayed when looking at the file.